# Method To Replace Array With Sum Of Each Element

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I need help with a concept that will be on my Java exam. I need to write a method that takes an array and returns a new array with each element being the sum of the elements before it. i.e the first array is {3, 2, 1, 4} and the array the method returns is {3, 5, 6, 10}

Here is my code so far:

```
public class testPrac1 {
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] array = {3, 2, 1, 4};

    for (int value: sum(array)) {
        System.out.print(value);
    }
}
public static int[] sum(int[] array) {
    int[] newArray = new int[array.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length ; i++) {
        if (i == 0){
            newArray[i] = array[0];
        }
        else 
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) 
                    newArray[i]  =  (array[i] + array[j]);
    }

    return newArray;
}

}
```

Comment: It's not homework, it's a concept I need to understand.

Comment: @ViralShah: The `homework` tag is obsolete already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And just to spice it up, how about:

```
public static int[] sum(int[] array) {
  int[] newArray = new int[array.length];

  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    newArray[i] = array[i];
    if (i > 0) {
      newArray[i] += newArray[i-1];
    }
  }

  return newArray;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I see that it makes sense to just use the newArray[i-1] as opposed to array[i-1] because newArray[i-1] is already the sum of the elements before.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) 
    newArray[i]  += array[j]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try your else part

```
 for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) 
     // newArray[i]  =  (array[i] + array[j]);
     newArray[i]  += array[j];
```

Answer (score 0):

just do this

```
 else 
        newArray[i]  = newArray[i-1] + array[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

The sum of the first k elements is the same as the sum of the first k-1 elements plus the kth element.

In the example you've given:

```
{3,2,1,4} --> {3,5,6,10}
3 = 3
3+2 = 5
3+2+1 = 5+1 = 6
3+2+1+4 = 6+4 = 10
```

So all you really need is:

```
newArray[0]=array[0];
for(int i=1; i<array.length; i++)
    newArray[i]=newArray[i-1]+array[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     public static int[] sum(int[] array) {
        int[] newArray = new int[array.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length ; i++) {
          for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) 
             newArray[i]  += array[j];
        }
        return newArray;
      }
```

you don't need the conditional, as `<=` will handle the case of `0`.  So  the loop just says go through the array and sum up all the values in positions that are <= to the current position in the array.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just try this simple piece of code:

```
int [] array = {3,5,1,4};
int newarray[]=new int[array.length];
int sum=0;
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
        {sum=sum+array[i];
        newarray[i]=sum;}
```